# Split text into speaker and text with regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
JOHN SMITH, GLOBAL HEAD OF YOUTUBE : Good morning, good 
afternoon, everyone . Before I hand over to facebook, I want to give a quick reminder of the reporting 
changes that have taken effect this filming of a tv show.  
 

 
BOBBY DUDE, GROUP FROM FACEBOOK:     Thanks, john smith lets talk about movies and films we watch when we are bored parents.
```

How can i create a regex pattern to split the text into speaker and text? For example to get this result:

```
string1: (speaker = JOHN SMITH, GLOBAL HEAD OF YOUTUBE, text  =  Good morning, good 
afternoon, everyone . Before I hand over to facebook, I want to give a quick reminder of the reporting 
changes that have taken effect this filming of a tv show.  
 )
```

etc

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76756499/edit) your question to include what you have tried so far to solve the issue? See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sxmhb2/1)):

```py
import re

text = """\
JOHN SMITH, GLOBAL HEAD OF YOUTUBE : Good morning, good
afternoon, everyone . Before I hand over to facebook, I want to give a quick reminder of the reporting
changes that have taken effect this filming of a tv show.



BOBBY DUDE, GROUP FROM FACEBOOK:     Thanks, john smith lets talk about movies and films we watch when we are bored parents. """

out = re.findall(
    r"^([^a-z:]+?)\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*(?=^[^a-z:]+?:|\Z)", text, flags=re.S | re.M
)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    (
        "JOHN SMITH, GLOBAL HEAD OF YOUTUBE",
        "Good morning, good\nafternoon, everyone . Before I hand over to facebook, I want to give a quick reminder of the reporting\nchanges that have taken effect this filming of a tv show.",
    ),
    (
        "BOBBY DUDE, GROUP FROM FACEBOOK",
        "Thanks, john smith lets talk about movies and films we watch when we are bored parents.",
    ),
]
```